# SpriteKit: childNodeWithName – Warning incompatible pointer types

Tags: sprite-kit

when I try to use:

```
SKSpriteNode *player = [self childNodeWithName:@"player"];
```

"Incompatible pointer types initializing 'SKSpriteNode *' with an expression of type 'SKNode *'"

How do I fix that?? Thanks!

Comment: cast the SKNode to SKSpriteNode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You fix it by converting your variable from `SKNode` to `SKSpriteNode`. It's called Type Casting.

```
SKSpriteNode *player = (SKSpriteNode *)[self childNodeWithName:@"player"];
```